# Exporting project with all files, properties and dependencies using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, export, qgs

I need to share a project with some students but I would like to share it simply in a sort of package file which would include the project and all the files (Vector and Rasters) with they properties and dependencies.
Looking at old posts it seems like that a plugin that used to work in the past (QConsolidate) is no longer supported.

How do I zip everything and share it, or what could be the best compromise to avoid to export each file into a dedicated folder to the share?

Comment: There is a QPackage plugin available which I have not used.  As Babel answers the QField sync is a good option.  It produces a package with the project file extension of qgs (and a backup qgs~)  that in my experience (limited to simple projects) opens just fine in QGIS desktop.  You can manually put all the files together in a folder with a project and on opening the project re-source the layers to the files in that folder (which works pretty well) and it's ready to go assuming you are using the default relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Project Packager by Tarot Osuji - https://github.com/tarot231

Although it doesn't have a rating yet it seems to have more than 2,000 downloads. So, I risked trying it.

It seems to be working fine, it creates a folder (which needs to different than the Project Home folder) with the QGIS project file and an EXTRA folder with all other files (shapefiles).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Your "package" already exist it is the **geopackage** file format. You're able to store all the components your project will require (vector/raster layers).

The **project itself** can also be embedded in the geopackage.

Even the images (raster/vector) or files (.pdf) you could have to use (for layouts or help files) can be inserted in the tables of the geopackage.

So there is no automatic/magic trick, but if you choose the geopackage scenario all you'll have to give to your students is a **single** file.

And for some more automatic process you can check the `package layers` treatment in QGIS toolbox (this treatment should gather all the layers of your project into a single geopackage)

Comment: Re: project itself - how do I export this to the new .gpkg? I saved my project into the original geopackage, but I can't select it as a layer (or a file) from the Package layers dialog.

Answer (score 5):

A good alternative to export the project plus the layers contained is the [QField Sync Plugin](https://qfield.org/docs/synchronise/qfieldsync.html). Description from QGIS plugin dialog:

> This plugin facilitates packaging QGIS projects for QField. It analyses the current project and suggests (and performs) actions needed to make the project working on QField.

The Plugin is intended to prepare project + data for use in QField, a QGIS-based app for use with mobile devices. However, these projects can be used with other QGIS desktop installations as well.

So based on features you need, this might be an option to consider. Plugin is free to use and no registration/account is required.

Comment: This should be marked as solution, as it is the only one that works with Raster Table in my Postgres DB.

Answer (score 2):

With the Mergin Plugin, you can package your project to a folder. It gives you an option to create "offline" version of your vector layers (e.g. PostGIS).

To package your project:
1- Install the plugin
2- Run the project creation wizard
3- Select the 2nd option to package all your layers to a folder

See the link for more information about using the packaging function:
https://help.cloudmergin.com/plugin-new-project

**Disclaimer**: we are the developers of the plugin.

Comment: The plugin requires a free account, it won't work without signing in. Why is that so?